# Converting string to long long

Tags: c, string, visual-studio-2012, type-conversion, long-long

I used the solution given in

[Troubling converting string to long long in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418262/troubling-converting-string-to-long-long-in-c)

to convert a string to long long in C. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

On compiling I am getting the error

> LNK2019: unreslved external symbol _+atoll referenced in function _main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  


int main(void) {
    char s[30] = { "115" };
    long long t = atoll(s);

    printf("Value is: %lld\n", t);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`atoll` is deprecated and seems not to be included in the newest VS release. Use `strtoll`

```
long long t = strtoll(s, NULL, 10);
```

If that is unavailable either then see if `_strtoi64` is (has the same prototype).

Comment: I tried strtoll but get the same error. Will give _strtoi64 and go. Thank you

Comment: atoll should be available in the latest VS, 2013. It wasn't in earlier versions because it's a C99 function and MS ignored C99 until very recently.  The same applies to strtoll.

Answer (score 2):

The atoll function was introduced to the standard C language in C99.

Unfortunately Microsoft ignored C99 for a long time and didn't implement any of its features in the Visual Studio C compiler, up to and including VS 2012.

This changed with VS 2013 which added considerable, but not complete, C99 support.

The easiest option is probably to use _strtoi64 which should be available, but be aware that this is a Microsoft specific function so probably won't work if you try to compile your code elsewhere.